# Get specific data out of different strings

Tags: json, object, get, find, postman

I'm new to JSON but in meantime I had success using search function on this page to get most of my problems solved.

Right now I'm faced to a problem since several days where I couldn't finde a appropriate solution.
Perhaps you can help me.

I have different JSON objects

```
{
   "nodes": {
      "001-001-001": {
         "hostname": "name1",
         "id": "001-001-001"
         }
      "002-002-002": {
         "hostname": "name2",
         "id": "002-002-002"
         }
      "003-003-003": {
         "hostname": "name3",
         "id": "003-003-003"
         }
}
```

Value of hostname and id is everytime unique.

Now I have the challange to search for a specific "hostname" and get the "id" value out of this object.

For example:

- Search for "hostname": "name2"
- Get "id"-value: "002-002-002"

Everything I've found until now is to get a specific "id" based on arrays. Unfortunately in my case I don't have an array.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data={
          "nodes": {
             "001-001-001": {
                "hostname": "name1",
                "id": "001-001-001"
                },
             "002-002-002": {
                "hostname": "name2",
                "id": "002-002-002"
               },
             "003-003-003": {
                "hostname": "name3",
                "id": "003-003-003"
                },
               "002-002-002": {
                "hostname": "name2",
                "id": "002-002-002"
                }
       }
       };
       
       function search(name){
       
         for (let key in data.nodes) {
            if(data.nodes[key].hostname==name){
                return data.nodes[key].id;
             }
         }
       }
       
        let output=search("name2");
        console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working fine.